# wrong color in color picker of photoshop

Tags: colors, rgb, photoshop

I have very strange in my Adobe Photoshop on my windows 10.
 [image]

My RGB color change to another color And I have no idea to why this bullshit happening.

I reinstalled photoshop application and still have this problem.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try changing your color profile (Edit > Color Settings)
- Make sure graphic drivers are fine
- Put this question in relevant stack exchange ([graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com))